# Python/Pandas: how to generate date ranges from month, quarter, year etc relative to a given timestamp?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, date-range

I have this dataframe

```
         2022-03-18
AAAMO00      33.001
AAAMO01      31.900
AAAMO02      30.800
AAAMO03      30.850
AAAQR01      30.850
AAAQR02      29.933
AAASN01      28.592
AAASN02      18.575
AAAYR01      20.700
```

'2022-03-18' is the "given timestamp", and 'AAA' is the product name, then when we have "MO" means month, and MO00 would be the next month compared to 2022-03-18, so April. MO01 = May etc

"QR" means "quarter". "QR01" would mean 2022-Q3 because the ref date 2022-03-18 is in 2022-Q1, hence QR00 is 2022-Q2, QR01 is 2022-Q3, the start and end date are just the start and end date of 2022Q3: 2022-07-01 and 2022-09-30 (QR00 is the NEXT quarter compared to the ref date, the same logic and naming convention as months)

From the dataframe I wish to get a new dataframe like this

[image]

How can I achieve this with Pandas? Thanks a lot.

(PS YR means year and SN means season, let's ignore the Season data for the moment :) )

Comment: How long exactly would a SN - season be?

Comment: I'm not quite understanding the QR stuff here. What should the start date be for `JKLQR01` and what should the end date be?

Comment: Season means summer and winter, but let's ignore season data for the moment. For quarter, as the ref date is in March, which is in 2022Q1 , hence QR00=2022Q2 hence QR01 = 2022Q3, the start and end date are just the start and end date of 2022Q3: 2022-07-01 and 2022-09-30

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like the one below will work for you.
Obviously, you will have to decide if the "YR" are relative to the current point in time or absolute

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.offsets import DateOffset

# Initial dataframe
contract = ['dJKLMO00', 'JKLMO01', 'JKLMO02', 'JKLMO03', 'JKLQR01', 'JKLQR02', 'JKLSN01',
            'JKLSN02', 'JKLYR01']
value = [33.001, 31.900, 30.800, 30.850, 30.850, 29.993, 28.592, 18.575, 20.700]
data = {'index': contract, '2022-03-21': value}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

# New dataframe
data_new = {'date': pd.to_datetime(df.columns[1]), 'values': df.iloc[0].iat[1]}
df_new = pd.DataFrame(data_new, index=[0])
print(df_new)
map_quarters = {"01": 4,
                "02": 7,
                "03": 10,
                }


for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if index == 0:
        print("Do nothing")
    else:
        if row['index'][-4:-2] == "MO":
            print(row)
            df_new = df_new.append(
                {'date': pd.to_datetime(df_new['date'][0] + DateOffset(months=int(row['index'][-2:]))),
                 "values": row.values[1]},
                ignore_index=True)
        if row['index'][-4:-2] == "QR":
            df_new = df_new.append(
                {'date': pd.to_datetime(df_new['date'][0] + DateOffset(months=int(map_quarters[row['index'][-2:]]))),
                 "values": row.values[1]},
                ignore_index=True)
        if row['index'][-4:-2] == "YR":
            df_new = df_new.append(
                {'date': pd.to_datetime(df_new['date'][0] + DateOffset(years=int(row['index'][-2:]))),
                 "values": row.values[1]},
                ignore_index=True)

# Resample and fill values in between
df_new = df_new.set_index('date').resample('D').ffill()

print(df_new)
```